# Can I open one application object and use it over and over?

Tags: .net, ms-office

I would like to write a visual basic application to scan tens of thousands of word files.  Can I create one application object for word (i.e. WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")) and use it to open, scan, and close each file in turn?
Or do I need to Quit and create a new application object for each file I need to scan?

Comment: You can call Application.WorkBooks.Open() and WorkBook.Close() as often as you like.  Only thing you can do wrong is not trying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I create one application object for word (i.e. WordApp =
>   CreateObject("Word.Application")) and use it to open, scan, and close
>   each file in turn? Or do I need to Quit and create a new application
>   object for each file I need to scan?

Create object only for once!

Use the Microsoft Visual Basic CreateObject function to return a Word Application object, and keep on changing the documents by opening and closing them properly.

```
Set wrd = CreateObject("Word.Application") 
wrd.Visible = True 
wrd.Documents.Open "C:\My Documents\Temp.doc"
// keep on opening/closing and changing your document here...
```

Comment: Thanks for the how to, but I was more interested in the "would it work", but Hans said it best.  I just got to try it.